# Remove more than one row at random from a pandas dataframe with an exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, random

I'm attempting to remove *x* number of `rows` from a `df` with an exception of a certain `row`.

`df`:

```
                  Main             Ing 
0                  A              Apple            
1                  B              Bread            
2                  Z              Cheese            
3                  E              Egg            
4                  D              Dough           
5                  X              Pasta  
etc.
```

I've attempted the following, with the intention of removing one `row`:

```
r = randint(0, df.shape[0])
df.drop(df.index[r])
```

*However, it doesn't seem to do anything.*

My goal is to randomly remove `x` number of `rows` from df, with the exception of a certain `row`, e.g:

`df.loc[df['Main'] == 'A']`

---

***Desired Output:***

E.G: If the number of `rows` to remove was `4`, with the exception of the `row` - `df.loc[df['Main'] == 'A']`, the output would be:

```
                  Main             Ing 
0                  A              Apple                      
2                  Z              Cheese                                
etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.sample`

```
df.drop(df[df.Main != 'A'].sample(4).index)

  Main     Ing
0    A   Apple
2    Z  Cheese
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great. What's the purpose of `.index` ?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.drop` will drop the rows that are specified by the index names passed. `pd.DataFrame.sample` randomly picked 4 rows, so I passed the indices of those rows in order for `drop` to do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

Random pick index from 1 : n (PS: index = 0 is the row you want to keep)

```
import random
df.drop(random.sample(range(1, df.shape[0]), 4),0)

Out[212]: 
  Main    Ing
0    A  Apple
4    D  Dough
```